# How to receive date from datetimepicker and save that into database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2

I need to receive a date from user, and save  that in database. I am using the following datetimepicker to receive the date, I receive the date as following,

It runs into following exception

```
  SEVERE: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented 
  as java.sql.Date
```

**Entered date**

```
   Thu Jun 13 00:00:00 EST 2012
```

How can I retrieve the date only to be able to save that into database?

**JSP**

```
  <sx:datetimepicker name="mydate"
                           label="myDate"
                           displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                           value="todayDate"/>
```

**Java**

```
...
private Date mydate;
...
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
getter

setter
```

**Database**

```
name     type
mydate   Date
```

Even when I use the following method as well to set the variable it throws the same exception

```
public Date getCurrentDate(){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Current Date" + dateFormat.format(date));
        return  date;
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement Struts2 type conversion

Comment: [doc](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html), or just use the [@DateTimeFormat](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) of Spring

Answer (score 0):

Change display format `dd-MMM-yyyy` to `MM-dd-yyyy`

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="mydate"
    label="myDate"
    displayFormat="MM-dd-yyyy"
    value="todayDate"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this conversion

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(struts2Date.getTime());
```

and save the *sqlDate* in mySQL table

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: There is no `struts2Date` in OP, you don't show what type is `struts2Date` and you don't know which type of date OP uses in action and in model, etc...